# Angular directive to add attributes to an element

Tags: angularjs

I have the following HTML / Angular code on a form:

```
<span class="error" ng-if="model.errors['message.email']" ng-bind="model.errors['message.email'][0]"></span>
```

I would like to use less code so the following would render the same:

```
<span class="error" model-validator="message.email" validator-errors="model.errors"></span>
```

**Note**

When validator-errors is not present then the default would be "errors" so I would get:

```
<span class="error" ng-if="errors['message.email']" ng-bind="errors['message.email'][0]"></span>
```

**UPTATE 1**

I tried the following:

```
.directive('modelValidator', function () {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

      var validator = element.attr('model-validator');
      if (validator === "null")
        return;

      var errors = element.attr('validator-errors');

      element.attr('data-ng-if', errors + "['" + validator + "']");

      element.attr('data-ng-bind', errors + "['" + validator + "'][0]");

    }
  };
```

But this is not adding the attributes ...

**UPDATE 2**

The directive is working. I would like to just add a few things:

1. How to use an attribute to specify which variable contains the errors?

   On the directive "scope.model.errors" would be "scope.allErrorsToDisplay".
2. Do I need to watch all scope? Can I only watch model.errors? 
   Or considering (1), watch the variable in "validator-errors"?

Here is my current code:

angular.module('Application')

```
.directive('validator', function () {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false,
    link: function (scope, element, attribute) {

      scope.$watch(function () {

        if (scope.model.errors) {
          if (scope.model.errors[attribute.validator]) {
            element.show();
            element.text(scope.model.errors[attribute.validator][0]);
          } else
            element.hide();
        } else
          element.hide();

      });
    }
  }
});
```

**Update 3**

This seems to do everything I need. 
Does anyone has any suggestion to improve it?

```
angular.module('app')

  .directive('validator', ['$parse', function ($parse) {

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: false,
      link: function (scope, element, attributes) {                

        scope.$watch(function () {

          var errors = $parse('validatorErrors' in attributes ? attributes["validatorErrors"] : 'model.errors')(scope);

          if (errors) {
            if (errors[attributes.validator]) {
              element.show();
              element.text(errors[attributes.validator][0]);
            } else
              element.hide();
          } else
            element.hide();

        });
      }
    }
  }]);
```

Comment: Asking how to write something is not likely to get you a response. Showing what you tried and what  problems you are having most likely will get you some help

Comment: @charlietfl I just added what I have been trying ... I am just starting with directives so I am not sure of how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is too complicated. The power of directives is that you don't have to add other directives to accomplish what you want. If i'm understanding your question correctly, you want your element to display a message if the error exists. [How about this?](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/bdEGjZ?editors=101)

```
<!-- html -->
<div ng-controller="mainController">
  <div validate="email"></div>
  <div validate="name"></div>
</div>
```

```
// controller
function mainController ($scope) { 
  $scope.model = {
    errors: {
      email: 'Your email is invalid!'
    , name: undefined
    }
  } 
}

// directive
function validate () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A'
  , replace: false
  , link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
      if (scope.model.errors[attr.validate]) {
        elem.text(scope.model.errors[attr.validate]);
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

**[codepen](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/bdEGjZ?editors=101)**

Comment: I see what you mean ... But I needed to add Watch because the errors change on form submission. Now I am missing only one feature. Could you take a look at my Update 2? Thank you.